# operator undefined when validating user input

Tags: java, validation

```
ages= new int[num];
    genders = new String[num];
    emails = new String[num];
    salaries = new double[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your age for person "+(i+1)+": ");
        ages[i] = in.nextInt();
        if (ages<20 ||ages>30){
            System.out.println("invalid age please re enter again");
            ages[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
```

Hi guys i am trying to validate user input in this case its the age which should not be below 20 and above 30 but i am getting an error saying "The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int" i would appreciate any help

Comment: ```ages``` is an array, you can't compare an array with a number. You have to compare ```ages[i]<20```

Comment: perfect that solved it. and also how do i continuously take user input for the age till the user enters the correct age?

Comment: Use a ```do..while``` loop with the while condition being ```while(!(ages[i]<20 ||ages>30))```

Comment: @Siddhartha why the `!`? That would continue the loop as long as the age is *invalid*.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Brainfreeze. Don't need the ```!```.

Comment: i'm trying to write the contents of the user input to a file but it creates the file but doesnt write to it could you tell me why?
here is my code
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("enter filename");
  Filename=in.next();
  PrintWriter outputFile  =new PrintWriter(Filename);
  outputFile.println(ages);
  getInput();
  display();}
 public static void display() throws FileNotFoundException{
  for (int i = 0; i < genders.length; i++) {
System.out.println(ages[i]+";"+genders[i]+";"+emails[i]+";"+salaries[i])}}

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ages < 20 || ages > 30){...}
```

should be:

```
if (ages[i] < 20 || ages[i] > 30) {...}
```

`ages` is an `int` array. You can apply `conditional operators` on the elements of this array but not on the array itself.

Comment: perfect that solved it. and also how do i continuously take user input for the age till the user enters the correct age?